# Can't upload Configurable product via CSV - can't find common element with products erroring?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, configurable-product, import-products

I have been staring down this spreadsheet for the last six hours, so any help is greatly appreciated.

I am trying to upload about 2K SKUs of apparel product, I'm uploading via CSV. Of my about 80 products, 60 of them are erroring on me and I can not figure out why.

After some trial and error I discovered that my validation errors disappear if I delete the configurable_variations column, but that doesn't do me any good because I need my simple product associated to the configurable product.

For the life of me, I can not figure out what the erroring out products have in common.

I know that the few products that are working are actually working, because a test upload of the configurable product ST657-master and all associated simple product worked perfectly.

The Data Validation error is as follows:

> Invalid option value in row(s): 2701, 2702, 2703, 2704, 2705, 2706, 2707, 2708, 2709, 2710, 2712, 2713, 2714, 2715, 2718, 2720, 2721, 2722, 2724, 2725, 2726, 2727, 2728, 2729, 2730, 2731, 2732, 2739, 2740, 2741, 2742, 2743, 2744, 2745, 2746, 2747, 2748, 2749, 2750, 2752, 2753, 2755, 2756, 2760, 2761, 2764, 2768, 2769, 2772, 2773, 2774, 2775, 2776, 2777, 2778, 2779, 2780, 2781, 2784, 2786

And my CSV is here - 
[(Dropbox Link)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qkffwrg4lutgwct/sanmar_product_upload_stackexchange.csv?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure all the `Categories` and `Product Attributes` are already configured and match what is in your CSV **exactly**. Make sure your configurable products appear **after** all of your simple products in the CSV, because if the import process finds a configurable product that requires a simple product variation that hasn't been loaded yet, it will error. Also make sure the `configurable_variations` contain not just the sku, but also all attributes for the simple product with that sku.

If all else fails, try manually configuring one of your configurable products and a couple of its simple products, and export them to CSV. Compare the exported CSV to what you're trying to import.

Comment: Thanks -  your reminders did it.

What had happened is there were attributes that had not been added to the system yet. I forgot about it, because I have an extension that automatically adds them to the system when I do CSV uploads, but it doesn't work for configurable product.